# Realtek HD audio only uses speakers and headphones as one audio device

Tags: windows-10, laptop, realtek-hd-audio

I want to record sounds using a desktop recorder, but for some reason only speakers can be used as a playback device. I want to separate the speakers and headphones since Realtek is using only one device.

I tried the options there, but I cannot find anything.

Realtek options panel:
[image: Realtek options panel]

Only one playback device visible:
[image: Only one playback device visible]

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, laptops can't use the internal speakers with an external one. It boils down to a physical switch that flips once an audio jack is plugged in and diverts the signal to that audio jack. This is by design (not a software thing)

**The simplest solution is to add a second sound output device such as a USB audio interface or a USB speakers/headphones.**

[image: example of a USB audio interface]